# Problem with Ubuntu Phone SDK demo app

Tags: installation, application-development, virtualbox, ubuntu-touch, opengl

I have installed the Ubuntu phone SDK on a VirtualBox VM running Ubuntu Precise (12.04.2 LTS) as the guest OS.
The "guest extensions" have been installed.
The guest OS kernel is 32 bit 3.2.0-37 without PAE.

I followed the installation instructions for the SDK on http://developer.ubuntu.com, and the installation seemed to go smoothly.
However, when I attempt to run the demo "Currency Converter" app, `qmlscene` reports many errors with the form:

`OpenGL Warning: XGetVisualInfo returned 0 visuals for 0x8db7f98`

ultimately followed by the message:

`Unrecognized OpenGL version`

A black box pops up, but nothing is drawn within it.   Does anyone know what might be causing this problem?

Comment: Suspect this may be a qt bug so filed a bug upstream https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32225

Answer (score 2):

simply disable the 3d graphic accelaration in the virtualbox vm settings and it will work.
Put both off 3d and 2d accelaration

Answer (score 1):

I had been using a pretty old laptop to run virtualbox.  I installed virtualbox on a newer Macbook Pro, and re-installed Ubuntu + Phone SDK.    Now the demo app works, so my problem may have been trying to run on too old a machine.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Ubuntu SDK makes use of OpenGL ES to render widgets, because it can use hardware accelerated graphics for it even on mobile devices.  VirtualBox, however, doesn't currently support OpenGL ES in it's virtual GPU, so it can't run any Ubuntu SDK apps.

Comment: It seems to be an upstream bug in Qt: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-32225

Answer (score 0):

For me , the black box was an error in the code , usually the UI part, look in the debug Qt Creator gives you and make sure you are using QML Scene (just to double check)

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can see on the [page of the currency converter app](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/mobile/currency-converter-phone-app/) you need Ubuntu 12.10 instead of 12.04 (which I think is quite awkward btw).

I would start with upgrading to 12.10 and then try again..

Good luck!

ps. I am also starting to look into developing an app for the Ubuntu Phone.

Comment: No need of 12.10 , my self tried in 12.04.

Comment: That's correct but there were some problems using 12.04. See [this thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/235440/how-do-i-install-the-qml-toolkit-on-12-04).

Comment: I upgraded to 12.10.   The problem did not go away.